# What does 'group_list' object has no attribute 'object' mean?

Tags: python, django, listview

I want to create listview and createview on the same screen, but I do not understand the meaning of the current error "'group_list' object has no attribute 'object'".

I tried to create it on the basis of createview, but the list was confused.
I also tried to create and inherit the createview and listview classes, but the same error occurred.

```
#error
'group_list' object has no attribute 'object'
```

```py
#forms
class GroupRequestForm(mixins.BaseModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = belong
        fields = ('group',)
```

```py
#view

class group_list(ListView,ModelFormMixin):
  model = group
  form_class = GroupRequestForm
  template_name = 'group/group_list.html'
  context_object_name = 'group_list'
  queryset = group.objects.all()

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

# class group_list(CreateView,):
#   form_class = GroupRequestForm
#   template_name = 'group/group_list.html'
#   success_url = reverse_lazy('group:group_list')
#
#   def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
#     context_data = super(group_list, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
#     context_data['group_list'] = group.objects.all()
#     return context_data
#
#   def form_valid(self,form):
#     user = self.request.user
#     # POST.get('user_id')
#     form.instance.user = user
#     return super().form_valid(form)

# class group_list(ListView):
#   model = group
#   context_object_name = 'group_list'



# class group_request(CreateView):
#   model = models.belong
#   form_class = GroupRequestForm
#   emplate_name = 'group/group_list.html'
#   success_url = reverse_lazy('group:group_list')
#
#   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#     self.object = self.get_object()  # assign the object to the view
#     form = self.get_form()
#     if form.is_valid():
#       email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
#       return self.form_valid(form)
#     else:
#       return self.form_invalid(form)
#
# class GroupListRequest(group_list,group_request):
#   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
#
#     formView = group_request.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
#     listView = group_list.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
#     formData = formView.context_data['form']
#     listData = listView.context_data['group_list']
#     context = {'form': formData, 'group_list': listData}
#     return render(request, 'group/group_list.html', context)
```

I want to create listview and createview on the same screen.

**Postscript**

```
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 136, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 67, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/t.a/anaconda3/envs/person/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 94, in get_context_data
    if self.object:
AttributeError: 'group_list' object has no attribute 'object'
```

```
#urls
app_name = 'groups'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.group_list.as_view(),name='group_list'),
]
```

Comment: Where is the stack trace?

Comment: generically it means there's a path through your code which accesses self.object in a group_list instance before one has been set - setting seems to happen in your post method. We can't see enough of your code (or the backtrace, as just noted) to know more.

Comment: Added error details.

Answer (score 0):

There was a part of the site I was referring to that was wrong, and the error disappeared when I corrected it.
Thank you very much.